# Combinatorics grouping

Tags: c#, grouping, combinatorics

I'm looking for an algorithm in c# that solves a combinatorics problem:

Assume i have the objects 1,2,3,4

I want to get all possible ways to group these object in multiple groups, that each time contain all objects. Order is not important. Example:

<1,2,3,4>
<1,2 / 3,4>
<1,3 /  2,4>
<1,4 / 3,2>
<1,2,3 / 4> 
<1,2,4 / 3>
<1,3,4 / 2> 
<2,3,4 / 1>
<1,2 / 3 / 4 > 
<1,3 / 2 / 4> 
<1,4 / 3 / 2> 
<2,3 / 1 / 4> 
<4,3 / 1 / 2> 
<1 / 2 / 3 / 4>

In the first case there is one group that contain all 4 objects. Next are cases with 2 groups that contain all objects in many different ways. The last case is 4 groups, that each one contains only one object.

Comment: What about `< 1,2 / 3 / 4 >` and other groupings of size 3?

Answer (score 1):

Start with <1>. With the addition of each new object, for each of the previous solutions, it can go into any of the groups or a new group of its own.

```
1: <1>
12: <1> => {<1,2> <1|2>}
123: <1,2> => {<1,2,3> <1,2|3>}, <1|2> => {<1,3|2> <1|2,3> <1|2|3>}
1234: <1,2,3> => {<1,2,3,4> <1,2,3|4>},
      <1,2|3> => {<1,2,4|3> <1,2|3,4> <1,2|3|4>},
      <1,3|2> => {<1,3,4|2> <1,3|2,4> <1,3|2|4>}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose algorythm is common, not C# algorythm. 
There are some approaches how to group all possible ways (with some restrictions)  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129805/algorithm-to-determine-possible-groups-of-items)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). There's some C# code in another SO answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343654/c-data-structure-to-mimic-cs-listlistint/349919#349919).